# Search string value from mssql column, regex, group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

These data:

```
ID     Desc
1      CUSTSEG
2      CUSTSEG;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCBISOA;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCBISOA
3      CUSTSEG;HKM
4      CUSTSEG;HKM;HKM
5      CUSTSEG;HKM;HKM;HKM;HKM;HKM;HKM;HKM
6      CUSTSEG;PHPM
7      CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU
8      CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;ATM
```

must be queried into this format:

```
COUNT  Desc
1      ATM
4      CARDMNU
2      CRC
2      CRCBISOA
8      CUSTSEG
10     HKM
3      PHPM
```

How can I achieve this using? Substring? I've tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CallTraversalLog
FROM [IVR].[dbo].[tblReportData] 
WHERE CallTraversalLog Like '%CUSTSEG%'
GROUP BY CallTraversalLog
```

But the resultset I got is

```
COUNT    Desc
1        CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;ATM
1        CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CARDMNU;CRC
1        CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCBISOA
2        CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CC
3        CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRC
2        CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRC;CARDMNU;CRC
1        CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRC;CRC;CRC;CARDMNU;CRC
25       CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION
4        CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION;CRCENROLL
55       CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCAPST
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the strings and count the items. You need a table valued function that splits a string by delimiter. If you don't want to write your own function you can easily google one. Then `CROSS APPLY` the function to your table and count the items.

```
SELECT s.item, count(*)
FROM [IVR].[dbo].[tblReportData] d
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(d.CallTraversalLog, ';') s
GROUP BY s.item
```